# ¿como llamar un nombre con condicion de duplicidad Oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Me veo un poco confundido al tratar de construir una query que traiga los Nombres (de la columna ENAME) de todos los empleados(de la tabla employees) que no se registraron en el curso de JAVA (de la tabla registrations) en la columna attendee esta la llave foranea de empleado (código de curso JAV)

Intente con la siguiente consulta, la cual me trae los registros de empleados que estan en los demás cursos, omitiendo jav.

```
SELECT A.ENAME, B.COURSE
FROM EMPLOYEES A
INNER JOIN REGISTRATIONS B ON A.EMPNO=B.ATTENDEE
WHERE A.EMPNO = B.ATTENDE AND COURSE <> 'JAV'
```

Sin embargo no quiero que me traiga el nombre de alguien que alguna vez se registro en el curso jav.
ej:

```
cod|ename|course
  1|Juan |sql
  2|Pedro|sql
  1|Juan |jav
```

Ahora, lo que busco es algo similar a:

```
cod|ename|course
  2|Pedro|sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo quieres los datos de los empleados que no se han registrado nunca en el curso de java, la forma más clara de hacerlo es:

```
SELECT  A.ENAME
        FROM EMPLOYEES A
        WHERE A.EMPNO NOT IN (SELECT ATTENDE 
                                     FROM REGISTRATIONS 
                                     WHERE COURSE = 'JAV')
```

Es decir: Todos los empleados que no estuvieran en `REGISTRATIONS` con la condición de `COURSE = 'JAV'`

Comment: Creo que hay un problema con este query. No se tiene acceso a la informacion del curso (Tabla `B` no existe y no es accesable desde un subquery).

Comment: Tenia unas pequeños observaciones, pero fue la query que resolvió mi duda, muchas gracias! perdón por la novatada haha.

Comment: @cavpollo, gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto te deberia de funcionar:

```
SELECT A.ENAME, B.COURSE
  FROM REGISTRATIONS B
  LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES A ON A.EMPNO = B.ATTENDEE
  WHERE B.COURSE <> 'JAV'
```

Como funciona:

```
SELECT *
  FROM REGISTRATIONS B
```

Lo anterior te trae todos los registros. Entonces los filtramos para solo tener aquellos que no son `JAV`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM REGISTRATIONS B
  WHERE B.COURSE <> 'JAV'
```

Teniendo ya los registros filtrados, queremos saber quien esta asignado:

```
SELECT *
  FROM REGISTRATIONS B
  LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES A ON A.EMPNO = B.ATTENDEE
  WHERE B.COURSE <> 'JAV'
```

Y por ultimo se seleccionan que columnas son las relevantes para tu query:

```
SELECT A.ENAME, B.COURSE
  FROM REGISTRATIONS B
  LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES A ON A.EMPNO = B.ATTENDEE
  WHERE B.COURSE <> 'JAV'
```

Ahora, que es un `LEFT JOIN`? Es una operacion que se encarga de encontrar la interseccion entre ambas tablas, y adherirsela al resultado de la primera tabla (`REGISTRATIONS` en nuestro caso).

[image: Left Join]

Puedes [leer un poco mas al respecto aqui](https://www.imaginanet.com/blog/diferencias-entre-join-left-join-y-right-join.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, como resultado obtuve el mismo reporte que tenia anteriormente, sin embargo ya que estoy en etapa de aprendizaje tu explicación del left join me fue muy útil.